# Qt5 ini file that needs updating in case of a crash

Tags: c++, qt5, ini

I'm writing a simple peer to peer instant messenger for a local network.  It uses an ini file to parse a UUID to use as an identifier across the network.  The ini file is accessed through a QSettings object.  I have written functionality to enable multiple instances of the program to be run on the same computer.  When the first program is run, it reads the ini file for the first entry and if one exists reads it, and replaces it with "INUSE".  When closing, it replaces the key value with the original UUID.  If another instance of the program reads the ini file and reads an INUSE as the first key value, it creates another after it, takes it, and puts an INUSE tag on the second key value.

This works fine, however, if the program crashes the UUID that was "INUSE" will be lost and INUSE will remain until manually taken out.  How can I account for crashing with a system that accomplishes the same thing?

Ive taken a look at QLockFile but can't wrap my head around exactly how I would implement such a system.

Any comments are appreciated.

The current format of the ini file is as follows:

```
[uuid]  
1={uuid1}  
2={uuid2}
```

while program 1 is executing

```
[uuid]  
1=INUSE  
2={uuid2}
```

and after a normal end of program

```
[uuid]
1={uuid1}
2={uuid2}
```

Essentially what I need is a way of preserving data between program executions but also signal to other instances that said data is currently being used.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first thing is to identify why is your program crashing. In order to choose the better solution.

QLockFile allows you to prevent multiple process accesing the same file. So this only will be usefull to you if the program is crashing beacuse of that.

What ever is the reason your program is crashing, I would recomend the use of exceptions to perform the correct actions when this occurs:

```
try {
    // Some of your code
} catch (exception &e)
{
    // Some error occured, do something about it.
    // Like restoring your UUID.
}
```

You can read more about exception [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/), and you can always use the QT version [Qexception](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qexception.html).

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  The program does not crash at any point that I'm currently aware of, however, if it is ever sent a SIGKILL message on unix or the equivalent on Windows, the situation in my original post appears

Comment: @cbpeckles Then your question it's kind of bad worded IMO. I don't think you wouldn't get the answer you want if you don't fix it.